# Launching the app store dialog box?

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad

I just noticed in iOS 6 that in your default Mail app, if you tap an itunes URL, an app store dialog box actually opens displaying the app's details.

There's no redirect to the app store! This box shows the screenshots, descriptions, etc. as if you were already in the app store.

I'm wondering if its possible to launch this box from inside my own app. I currently use itms-apps:// which naturally leaves my app, and goes to the app store.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are developing for iOS 6+ only, you can use [SKStoreProductViewController](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/StoreKit/Reference/SKITunesProductViewController_Ref/Introduction/Introduction.html).

Something like this:

```
SKStoreProductViewController *storeViewController = 
          [[SKStoreProductViewController alloc] init];

    storeViewController.delegate = self;

    NSDictionary *parameters =
         @{SKStoreProductParameterITunesItemIdentifier: 
              [NSNumber numberWithInteger:333700869]}; //Identifier of the item you want to buy.

    [storeViewController loadProductWithParameters:parameters 
         completionBlock:^(BOOL result, NSError *error) {
        if (result)
            [self presentViewController:storeViewController
                               animated:YES
                             completion:nil];
    }];
```

(Code from [this](http://www.techotopia.com/index.php/Making_Store_Purchases_with_the_SKStoreProductViewController_Class) tutorial.)